# Unable to access object property even if it clearly exists

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude with the node-geocoder.
I've configured everything correctly. I've got the API key and all I need.

I am getting the location as shown in the snippet for the first time (when creating the object to be inserted in the database)

```
  geocoder.geocode(req.body.location, function (err, data) {

//i have some more variables declared here but those do not matter



     var lat = data.latitude;
      var lng = data.longitude;
      var location = data.formattedAddress;


   var newPost = {name: name, image: image, description: desc, author:author, location: location, lat: lat, lng: lng};
```

So far so good. But when I try to get the location again using, I believe something that does the exact same thing, properties like `data.latitude` or `data.formattedAddress` return undefined.

I tried changing some variable names to avoid possible name collisions. There are no possible collisions left.

```
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

//settings
var options={
    provider:"google",
    httpAdapter: "https",
    apiKey:"..."
};

var geocoder=NodeGeocoder(options);
var geocoderUpdate=NodeGeocoder(options);


//...


//WHEN CREATING(IT WORKS)

 geocoder.geocode(req.body.location, function (err, data) {

//i have some more variables declared here but those do not matter

      var lat = data.latitude;
      var lng = data.longitude;
      var location = data.formattedAddress;


   var newPost = {name: name, image: image, description: desc, author:author, location: location, lat: lat, lng: lng};



//WHEN TRYING TO UPDATE (DOESN'T WORK)

geocoderUpdate.geocode(req.body.location, function (err, dataUpdate) {

      var latUpdate = dataUpdate.latitude;
      var lngUpdate = dataUpdate.longitude;
      var locationUpdate = dataUpdate.formattedAddress;
    var newData = {name: req.body.name, image: req.body.image, description: req.body.description, location: locationUpdate, lat: latUpdate, lng: lngUpdate};
```

The `console.log(dataUpdate)` returns the whole objects which is good. So when I tried to do `console.log(dataUpdate.longitude)`, I've got undefined instead of the number value of the property which is very unexpected.

Comment: Could you try to 'console.log(typeof(data));' and let us know the result

Comment: would be also great to console.log(data); where you want to retrieve these properties and show us the result.

Comment: try Console.log(dataUpdate['longitude'])

Answer (score 0):

I failed to notice that it returns an array, noted from the square brackets. 
That makes sense. I had to call for `data[0].longitude` instead of `data.longitude`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that i forgot to make the location values a must have when creating the object.
Still, the problem with extracting the properties from the object still persists

i tried the following:

`console.log(typeof(data))` returned
`object`

`console.log(data);` returned the whole object: (i tried "Lisbon" as input data for the geocoder)

```
[ { formattedAddress: 'Lisbon, Portugal',
    latitude: 38.7222524,
    longitude: -9.1393366,
    extra:
     { googlePlaceId: 'ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ',
       confidence: 0.5,
       premise: null,
       subpremise: null,
       neighborhood: 'Lisbon',
       establishment: null },
    administrativeLevels: { level1long: 'Lisbon', level1short: 'Lisbon' },
    city: 'Lisbon',
    country: 'Portugal',
    countryCode: 'PT',
    provider: 'google' } ]
```

and `console.log(dataUpdate['longitude']);` returned `undefined`

It is the node-geocoder from the npm package configured to use google maps.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information. Answers are for writing answers, not for clarifying your question. After you finish editing your question, you should delete this.